# Slick to manage Array[byte] in PostgreSQL with Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, byte, slick

We are having a few issues managing images in the database with Slick. They are stored in a Array[Byte] format. Every source I read informs me it should work, but I keep getting this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter conv: scala.slick.jdbc.GetResult[Array[Byte]]
```

The compiler is telling me that no mapper is found for Array[Byte]. I must be missing a simple import, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Please also add the query you are using.

Comment: Here is the query I execute: Q.queryNA[Array[Byte]]("SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = 1")

Answer (score 3):

You need an implicit `GetResult` in scope to map from the db result to the `Array[Byte]` that you want.  Try adding the following just before your query:

```
implicit val GetByteArr = GetResult(r => r.nextBytes)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Because of the deadline, we took the easy way out of saving the bytes as a file. We might use your input in the near future, when we have more time. Thanks again.